# Vimeo's "Non Commercial Use

Tags: vimeo

Vimeo's terms of services clrearly states:

> Non Commercial Use Only
>
> If you need a site to power your business' videos, please try one of
>   the many commercial video hosts out there. We remove commercial
>   content that violates our Guidelines without warning.

However, it seems Dropbox is using a Vimeo video on its homepage to showcase their product. Is this against the terms of use? Is this tolerated?

[I'm asking because I am considering to do something similar for my homepage.]

Comment: They have likely some sort of private agreement.

Comment: Dropbox is probably using Vimeo PRO, which gives them additional commercial rights. http://vimeo.com/pro

Comment: Justin, please read our [FAQ] … all but one of your questions are sooner or later going to be closed. YouTube / Vimeo is an online service, not computer software, therefore off topic. Especially legal issues.

Comment: @slhck: Thanks. Could you suggest a more appropriate place?

Comment: If you have specific questions about the usage of YouTube, consider looking at [webapps.SE]. Implementation of websites (thus concrete programming problems with HTML, CSS, JS) are better asked on [SO]. Just make sure your question fits the FAQ.

Comment: @slhck: Ok, I'll be more careful in the future.

Comment: Sure, no problem! If you have any question about where to ask what, you can also come to [chat] or ask us on [meta].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i'd suggest asking dropbox and vimeo. Particually when legal matters are concerned. Nothing anyone says here can be conclusive.